# Форматирование mac-address

Tags: python

Есть mac-address вида

```
user_name = "fe85.de19.c116"
```

как оригинальнее сделать чтобы получился вид

```
 user_name = "fe:85:de:19:c1:16"

def sanitizeMac(mac):
     temp = mac.replace(":", "").replace("-", "").replace(".", "").upper()
     return temp[:2] + ":" + ":".join([temp[i] + temp[i+1] for i in range(2,12,2)])
```

Comment: Можно регулярками заморочиться. (Интересно, это нормально везде, где задача связана с парсингом текста пытаться применить регулярные выражения, или перебор ? :)  

    import re
    
    user_name = "fe85.de19.c116"
    print ( re.sub( "\\.|(?<=\\w\\w)(?=\\w\\w)" , ":", user_name) )

http://ideone.com/eOfEod

Answer (score 3):

```
u":".join([u"%s:%s" % (x[:2], x[2:]) for x in user_name.split('.')])
```